# SearchBar in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

Currently my UISearchBar is in the Header but that doesn't let me use the index titles on the right to go straight to search.

If I implement the UISearchBar as a Cell, I can go to the searchbar with the index titles but when I start the search at a point I must reload data to hide the index titles which kills the uikeyboard because the searchbar cease to exist for a moment.

How can I implement this so when I touch UITableViewIndexSearch It goes to the searchbar and instead of going to this non existant section, goes to the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try reloading all the sections except your search bar section. Something like this (assuming the search bar is in the first section).

```
[tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1, [tableView numberOfSections])] 
         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Hope that helps!